# Assigning collectively to a struct

Tags: c, struct, bit-manipulation, unions, twos-complement

I have a struct of 4 bits: A,B,C and D. I wish to be able to refer to them independently (by their names) but also assign to them collectively. For example, if I said  `variables = 11;` , I would get A, B & D equal to 1, and C = 0, as 8 = 1011 in binary.

My approach to this is to have a union of a 4 bit  `int`  and a   `struct`  of 4, 1-bit  `int`  types.

However, I appear to have it beginning to work - however, when printing out, I keep getting 2's complement negative numbers instead of the numbers I am putting in - what am I doing wrong? When debugging, I notice that assigning a number to the union seems to set all the high-end bits to 1 - which surely shouldn't occur!?

Thanks very much for feedback and help! Code so far is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
typedef enum boolean {
    FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1
} bool;
typedef struct names {
    int A :1;
    int B :1;
    int C :1;
    int D :1;
} var_names;
typedef union variables {
    int number :4;
    var_names names;
} variables;

int main() {
    variables vars = { 0 };
    vars.number = 10;
    printf("Overall number: %d\n", vars.number);
    printf("A:\t%d\nB:\t%d\nC:\t%d\nD:\t%d\n", vars.names.A, vars.names.B,
            vars.names.C, vars.names.D);
    return 0;
}
```

And the printout of this program is:

```
Overall number: -6
A:  0
B:  -1
C:  0
D:  -1
```

Comment: Have you tried using unsigned int for your bits?

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks very much - out of interest - why should that make a difference though? I don't see why after assigning a number, it should appear differently?

Comment: Well, a one bit signed int is a special case.  It can only take on the values `0` or `-1`.  When you assigned the bit a `1`, you actually assigned it a `-1`.  Similarly, if you assigned the value `12` to a four bit signed bitfield, you would actually be assigning the value `-4`, because you used a value too large for the signed bitfield.

Comment: Bit fields are best avoided, they add unnecessary complexity and their representation is implementation defined. It is better to use bit operations on unsigned types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `int` for a regular variable, it is a `signed int`. However, when you use type `int` in a bit-field, whether it is `signed` or `unsigned` is implementation dependent. It's better to be precise. For bit-fields of width 1, it is better to use `unsigned int`.